# log page load times

Tags: http, logging, browser

Okay so for example, In the Firefox firebug addon, there is the "Net" tab that shows everything requested on the page (all the images, js files, etc..) what the request domain is, and how long it took to request/receive a response (the "timeline").

I know other addons show this information in similar fashion (eg: httpfox, tamper data, chrome's js console, etc..) In any of these, I can highlight and c/p or I can rightclick c/p but I can't seem to find anything that lets me just export all rows of data to a text or csv file...does anybody have any suggested addons or programs for logging this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome/Firebug support exporting the data into a HAR (HTTP Archive file). You can then parse it yourself or use on-line viewers such as http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/, use it with Page Speed [SDK](http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/) etc.

You can also use HarLog to export the HAR data to a tab delimited file: http://www.imagossoftware.com/harlog/

Comment: I'm not seeing an option in firebug to export as a HAR file...howto?

Comment: You'll need NetExport extension for Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#NetExport